# How to point the domain apex to ghs.googlehosted.com or redirect it to www from an external DNS host that doesn't support ALIAS records?

Tags: google, dns, cname, google-sites

We are running a google hosted website (google apps).

According to this guide we can set `www.exawple.com` using a CNAME this part this clear

https://support.google.com/sites/answer/9068867?hl=en and https://support.google.com/sites/answer/9068867?hl=en

However, we also want the non-www version to open the google hosted site. And an A record is mandatory I think.

So both `www.example.com` and `example.com` should point to the google hosted site at `ghs.googlehosted.com`.

What DNS settings should I use so both `www.example.com` and `example.com` work with a google hosted website. Another option would be to redirect `non-www` to `www`. As long as it works.

We don't have the custom URL option.

Our DNS hoster is a normal DNS hoster in Europe (no big company)

[image]

Comment: Some dutch hoster. I have CNAME, A, AAAA, redirection .... .btw I also discovered that I dont have the custom URL option!!